# Robot Framework class inheritance

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a parent class like below.

```
class ABC (object):

   def __init__:
      //Do something

   def __del__():
     //Cleanup what you did
```

Test Suites are sub classes of ABC.

```
Class A(ABC):
    def __init__():

Class B(ABC):
    def __init__():
```

However, when I execute pybot -i  A.robot B.robot . ABC get created and destroyed and then again created  and destroyed. How can I make the ABC constructor be called once before any test case and ABC destructor called at the end?

I don't want to use **init**.robot
, because I don't want to the get tied with the framework. One of the requirement is to be able to plug the code out of RBF and still use it.

Can I make ABC a singleton?

Comment: your question doesn't seem to make sense. You don't normally write test suites in python, and the -i option refers to tags, not test cases or robot files, and even if you write test cases in python, you wouldn't name the files with a .robot suffix. Are you asking about _suites_, or are you actually asking about robot keyword _libraries_?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, it looks like you want to override things more than use a singleton.

If you instanciate 2 objects you'll initiate 2 parents.

```
a = A() # ABC 1
b = B() # ABC 2
```

But maybe what you want is something like this:

```
abc = ABC()
a = A()
a.ABC = abc
b = B()
b.ABC = abc
```

or changing your `__init__()` to `__init__(abc)`

```
abc = ABC()
a = A(abc)
b = B(abc)
```

Answer (score 0):

As written you question doesn't make much sense,since you can't write test suites in python. I'm going to guess you are asking about keyword libraries.

If you want a keyword library to be instantiated once when a suite gets executed, and destroyed after all the tests have run, you need to set the library scope. From the user guide section on [library scope](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope):

> Test libraries can control when new libraries are created with a class
>   attribute ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE . This attribute must be a string and it
>   can have the following three values:
>
> **TEST CASE**  A new instance is created for every test case. A possible suite setup and suite teardown share yet another instance.
>   This is the default.
>
> **TEST SUITE** A new instance is created for every test suite. The lowest-level test suites, created from test case files and containing
>   test cases, have instances of their own, and higher-level suites all
>   get their own instances for their possible setups and teardowns.
>
> **GLOBAL** Only one instance is created during the whole test execution and it is shared by all test cases and test suites.
>   Libraries created from modules are always global.

Here's an example with a class-based keyword library:

```
class ExampleLibrary:

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'

    def __init__(self):
        // do something

    def __del__(self):
        // do something
```

**Important**: python doesn't guarantee that the `__del__` method runs. If the example library is destroyed right before the interpreter exits, the object may be destroyed without calling `__del__` (which I think might be true about robot libraries).

Comment: Yes I have created ABC as GLOBAL and other Test cases as TES_SUITE. I would expect order of exec to be: ABC__init__() -->A__init()__ -->A__del__() -->B__init__()--> B__del() -->__ ABC__del()__. But happens is ABC__init__() -->ABC__del__()--> ABC__init()->__ A__init__()-->A()__del__-->ABC__del__(). Not sure why ABC__del__() is called right after the __init__() .

Comment: @kgunjikar: those don't look like robot test cases. Are you sure you are talking about the acceptance testing framework from robotframework.org? It would help if you stopped talking in abstract terms and orovided actual runnable code.